# Use accessToken in C# Lambda with Alexa Account Linking

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've set up Account Linking for Alexa using Azure AD. I'm using C# to write my Lambda function because .Net Core contains libraries I need for accessing Dynamics 365. I can't seem to get the `accessToken` in C#. In node.js, this was as easy as `var accessToken = session.user.accessToken`. Am I missing something here? I don't know how to get the token so I can use it to communicate with Dynamics 365. I know the OAuth portion is good, since I have accessed the token using node.js.

Answer (score 0):

The accessToken is in request body. You can fetch the accessToken by something like this:

```
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
    {
        var body = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var request = se.Deserialize<Alexa.StandardRequest>(body);
        var accessToken = request.session.user.accessToken;
    }
```

While Alexa.StandardRequest can be declared by following the Alexa request spec at https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-standard-request-types-reference Easiest way is to copy&paste the request json data to a IDE and paste it as class.